# Laravel: Is always read the newly written data after calling save() method of ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Code:

```
$item1 = Item::find(1);
$item1->foo = 1;
$item1->save();
$another_item1 = Item::find(1);
dd($another_item1->foo);//Is this value always 1?
```

My question:

1. Is always read the newly written data after calling `save()` method of ORM? In my example,  Is `$another_item1->foo` always 1?
2. If the answer to question 1 is not, how could I ensure I read the newly written data from the database?

Comment: Your question is hard to read but Laravel ORM works by the order of operation, meaning: if you save Item::find(1); and repeat it again the next row you will get the latest data that was previously submitted. The save() function simply writes an update sql statement to the db.

Comment: 1) run the code, the question will answer itself :)

Comment: @lagbox Yeah, I have run the code for about 10000 times, they all output 1. But that result doesn't mean it's always 1 in any circumstance.

Comment: @Sayakiss "they all output 1" - What do you mean by "they"? When you run `$item1->foo = 1;` then `$item1->save();` then immediately turning around and run `$another_item1 = Item::find(1);` on that same line.. it will always return `1` because you just told it to update the record data to `1`. You're looking up the same row..

Comment: @Sayakiss you just answered all your questions yourself, which was the point of this .. "In my example, is `$another_item1->foo` always 1?" in **your example**, yes, you said its yes .. you just answered your own questions there is nothing left to answer in your post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is always read the newly written data after calling save() method of ORM?

No, there is no `SELECT` ran after a `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement in this case.

> In my example, Is `$another_item1->foo` always `1`?

Based on your own comment, Yes.

> If the answer to question 1 is not, how could I ensure I read the newly written data from the database?

```
$model->save();
// Reload the current model instance with fresh attributes from the database.
$model->refresh();
// OR
// Reload a fresh model instance from the database.
$fresh = $model->fresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused about the `find()` function. `find()` is used to fetch one or many models by its / their primary key(s). The return value will either be a single model, a collection or `null` if the record is not found.

If you are looking to lookup multiple rows you need to run `Item::get();`

**Uses**

```
$Item = Item::find(1); // returns model or null
$Items = Item::find(array(1, 2, 3)); // returns selected Items in collection
$Items = Item::get(); // Returns all in collection
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent